# Return PDF documents

Tags: pdf, servicestack

I've tried implementing a custom formatter for returning PDF documents from ServiceStack. Without much luck, though. I've looked at the examples and pretty much copied the VCard sample, but replaced it with my code. My formatter looks something like this:

```
public class PdfFormatter
{
    private const string PdfFormatContentType = "application/pdf";

    public static void Register(IAppHost appHost)
    {
        appHost.ContentTypeFilters.Register(PdfFormatContentType, SerializeToStream, (t, s) => { throw new NotImplementedException(); });
    }

    public static void SerializeToStream(IRequestContext requestcontext, object dto, Stream outputstream)
    {
        ...
    } 
}
```

I've called Register from my AppHost and the Content Type Filter is added as expected. My problem is that SerializeToStream is only called when accessing the metadata for my methods. When I call the concrete method on servicestack, an HTML response is returned.

The URL called is: http://mydomain.com/api/pdf/reply/GenerateDocument

The request headers looks like this:

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,da;q=0.6
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Host:mydomain.com
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.64 Safari/537.31
```

The response headers look like this:

```
Cache-Control:private
Connection:Close
Content-Length:46
Content-Type:application/pdf; charset=utf-8
Date:Thu, 16 May 2013 19:59:27 GMT
Server:ASP.NET Development Server/11.0.0.0
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-Powered-By:ServiceStack/3,945 Win32NT/.NET
```

The response is actually PDF but the debugger doesn't break in SerializeToStream.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After registering the Content-Type, the client still needs to tell ServiceStack that it wants the PDF content type.

You can do this on the url:

```
http://example.org/myservice?format=pdf
```

via a [pre-defined route](http://www.servicestack.net/ServiceStack.Hello/#predefinedroutes):

```
http://example.org/pdf/reply/GenerateDocument
```

Or in the HTTP **Accept** header, e.g:

```
GET /myservice
Host: example.org
Accept: application/pdf
```

Comment: I tried that and it makes no difference. When requesting http://localhost/api/pdf/metadata?op=GenerateDocument SerializeToStream is called, but when calling http://localhost/api/pdf/reply/GenerateDocument?format=pdf SerializeToStream is not called.

Comment: Can you provide the complete HTTP Request and Response (using Fiddler/WebInspector or WireShark,etc) so we can see what's going on?

Comment: Request URL:http://localhost:36386/api/pdf/reply/GenerateDocument?format=pdf
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK

Comment: Request Headersview source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,da;q=0.6
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:36386
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.64 Safari/537.31
Query String Parametersview sourceview URL encoded
format:pdf

Comment: Response Headersview source
Cache-Control:private
Connection:Close
Content-Length:46
Content-Type:application/pdf; charset=utf-8
Date:Thu, 16 May 2013 19:52:08 GMT
Server:ASP.NET Development Server/11.0.0.0
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-Powered-By:ServiceStack/3,945 Win32NT/.NET

Comment: whoa, you should update the question with any code-blocks as it's unreadable in comments. If you're using the pre-defined routes you don't need `?format=pdf`. The response shows it's trying to return pdf as expected, so all seems fine from here. Are you debugging and sure it's not being called?

Comment: The request and response headers are not added to the question.

Comment: Is that the full response? because the body is empty atm.

Comment: Yes. I'm returning an empty response. Just tried returning an actual PDF from my method but as expected, the response is the same as before.

Comment: Can't see anything you've done wrong from what you've presented, but it's not something I can repro, so don't know what the issue is.